# How to remove div with id="app" in vue project public/index.html file?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I would like to remove the main div which is in public/index.html file.

Now when I build a project it looks like this:

```html
<body>
<div id="app">
//my code is displayed here
</div>
</body>
```

But I need to remove div with app id so it should look like this:

```html
<body>
//my code is displayed here
</body>
```

How I can achieve this in Vue3?

Answer (score 2):

You could specify `body` as the mount point:

```js
// main.js
createApp({}).mount('body')
```

If using a Vue CLI scaffold, note this would automatically replace the entire `body` contents from `public/index.html`, including the `div#app` and `noscript` boilerplate:

```html
<noscript>
  <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
</noscript>
```

Comment: Is there any way to replace only div#app and leave noscript tag?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of